# using "contains" for query key condition in dynamoDB

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query my dynamodb with contains comparison parameter, but it is not working

```
data= table.query(
    IndexName='farm_name-index',
    KeyConditionExpression = Key('user_name').eq(user_name)& contains(Key('farm_zone_id_time_stamp'),farm_zone_id_time_stamp)& Key('time_stamp').between(from_time,to_time) 
    )
```

and i am getting the following error :

```
name 'contains' is not defined: NameError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 25, in lambda_handler
    KeyConditionExpression = Key('user_name').eq(user_name)& contains(Key('farm_zone_id_time_stamp'),farm_zone_id_time_stamp)& Key('time_stamp').between(from_time,to_time)
NameError: name 'contains' is not defined
```

can any one tell me the right way to doit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do contains on a sort key. You can do equality, begins_with, or comparison operators only.

Here's the list from the docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions

Why? Because these are the operators that are efficient for pulling data out of a sorted list, such as is put under the sort key.

With DynamoDB you can use a filter expression for things like contains. It's not index optimized.